# What are the suitable choices of crampons for Scarpa Charmoz GTX Women boots?

Tags: mountaineering, boots, crampons

I have Scarpa Charmoz GTX Women boots for mountaineering (upper than 4000 m) in Iran. I want to find a good pair of crampons for them. I cannot choose automatic crampons but somebody says I can use newmatic or semi-automatic crampons. Is it correct? If yes which brands do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you'll need Newmatic crampons. The Charmoz GTX has a heel bail but no toe bail, which means you will need a strap over the toe. Many crampons today come with a choice of configuration between a step-in or toe-strap, and most step-ins can be refitted with a toe-strap after the fact as well.

The actual type and model of crampon recommended varies with the intended activity (and budget), however. So all else being equal, anything with a toe strap will work.
[image: BD Sabretooth with toe strap]

Comment: I'd like to add that one would prefer to make usage of a heel bail/welt and choose semi-automatic (aka newmatic) crampons, because completely strap bindings (aka universal crampons) hold on the boot not as good as semi-automatic ones.